# How computers draw transparency?

Tags: graphics, opacity

In real life, transparency (or opacity) can be explained in a "simple" way by how much an object can reflect light, or how much of it pass through.  So if an object is transparent light pass trough it, reflect on whatever is behind it and the light get back to us.

How computers simulate this behavior? I mean, we as developers, have many abstractions and APIs to set alpha levels and opacities of our pixels but how computers translates this into a bitmap to the screen?

What I think is happening: Both back and front colors are "combined" to result in a third color and this is then draw to screen. Eg: transparent white over back red on screen will be painted as pink!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is transparency actually implemented ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136028/how-is-transparency-actually-implemented), so it's kinda as you thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have it right.  The "back" color is combined with the "front" color in proportion to the opacity of the front color.

For a single color channel, e.g. red, with opacity from 0 to 1:

```
new = old * (1 - opacity) + front * opacity
```